# View and controller in asp.net mvc3 - controller should match a view one to one?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, action

I have a very typical situation in any application, where i have the following functionality:

- create new record
- edit existing record
- so other irrelevant actions

IMO, creating and editing should be served by the same view, but different actions. But it appears that I have to have the action name match the view name....would you use partial views for this? I would rather not complicate this scenario - which is very simple and appears in virtually every web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action can return a view with a diferent name this way:

```
public ActionResult OneName()
{
    return View("OtherName");
}
```

If you don't specify the view name (View("") then the view will be the view with the action name

Comment: that's precisely what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Partial views are an excellent answer. I'd suggest you look at how the MvcScaffold NuGet package does it. [See here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) or get the package in Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

I'd simply use the same action altogether and use the ID to determine if this is a new record or updating an existing one:

`/Forum/Post/Edit/0` create a new record

`/Forum/Post/Edit/10457` update a record with ID 10457

However, since you insist on using different actions, why not simply create 2 actions, both returning the same view?

```
public class PostController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Create(Post post)
    {
        // work your magic...

        return View("Edit", post);
    }

    public ActionResult Update(Post post)
    {
        // work your magic...

        return View("Edit", post);
    }    
}
```

If this doesn't work in your scenario, you're pretty much left with partial views.

Comment: `"I would simply use the same action altogether and use the ID to determine if this is a new record or an existing one"` - Terrible, TERRIBLE design.

Comment: @Dismissile I would accept that comment as the accepted answer... +1

Comment: @Dismissile How does it count as terrible design? Id=0 is generally considered a new record. Just about every piece of software uses ID to track records. If that's terrible design, we just rendered 99% of the applications in the world to be refactored. So please, prove your point.

Comment: @Dismissile one action\method - **one operation only** . Proved?

Comment: @gdoron having an opinion doesn't prove a fact. Having a well-founded one might actually lead you to finding one.